# inneficiency creating public and private keys

Tags: python, performance, runtime, rsa, public-key-encryption

this code is simply to create a public and private key pair (and use it on a single character) but if i use prime numbers greater than about 1500 then it takes far to long, to create these keys and encrypt/decrypt a single character.

my code is:

```
from math import gcd
import random

prime_numbers=[1223, 1033]

def phi_function(x):
    x=(p-1)*(q-1)
    return(x)

def is_coprime(x, y):
    z=gcd(x, y)
    if z==1:
        return True
    if z!=1:
        return False

def encryption_key_generator(x, y):
    list_p=[]
    for i in range(1, x):
        i2 = i+1
        if is_coprime(i2, y)==True:
            if is_coprime(i2, phi)==True:
                list_p.append(i+1)
    z=(list_p[len(list_p)-(random.randint(1, len(list_p)))], y)
    return z

def decryption_key_generator(x, y, z):
    list_p=[]
    for i in range(z):
        i2=i+1
        if (x*i2)%y == 1:
            list_p.append(i2)
    q=(list_p[len(list_p)-1], z)
    return (q)

p=prime_numbers[0]
q=prime_numbers[1]
n=p*q
phi=phi_function(n)
encryption_key=encryption_key_generator(phi, n)
decryption_key=decryption_key_generator(encryption_key[0], phi, n)
#print('encryption_key = '+str(encryption_key))
#print('decryption_key = '+str(decryption_key))

x=input('text:   ')

x1=ord(x)
y=(x1**(encryption_key[0]))%(encryption_key[1])
y=chr(y)

y1=ord(y)
z=(y1**(decryption_key[0]))%(decryption_key[1])
print(chr(z))
```

my question is, are there any methods or built in functions i can use here to make it run faster.
(if it makes any difference to the solution, its going to be used for a secure messaging app i'm in the process of building)

Comment: You really need to use more advanced algorithms for finding modular inverses, modular exponentiation, etc. There is the three argument [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function which will be much faster than your x**y % n code. And you can find many python examples online of the extended euclidean algorithm for find inverses.

Comment: i tried implimenting it and it says "TypeError: int object is not subscriptable" which part of it is breaking and what does subscriptable mean

Comment: also would you be able to explain how to create/use more advanced algoithms? or at least point me in the direction af a tutorial or something

Comment: Wikipedia is a good starting point, and I did mention the extended euclidean algorithm which you can enter into your favorite search engine and find a wealth of information.

Comment: i looked up the extended euclidean algorithm but i dont see how it can be used in my code, im a noob at encryption so i may have missed something obvious, but i just cant see how to impliment it, can you help?